# Eraser Tool for iOS with Hardness and softness

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-image

I'm implementing an eraser tool with MDScratchImageView (URL given below) for one of my drawing application. What I achieve is to erase the image with just hardness. How I can achieve the eraser smoothness and softness like showing in image:[image]

I've achieve the left bottom eraser but not getting any idea for smoothness and softness like showing in the dotted circle.

For the code block, please follow this URL: https://github.com/Andrew5/DHPRO/tree/f011fde2c3ac1dc4a3ea7c25fab0872df69a2c28/CollegePro/Class(%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5)/Other/%E9%A1%B9%E7%9B%AE/Animations/Animations/MDScratchImageView

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: One way is to create a png image with your desired smoothness/softness and use that image as the eraser.

Comment: Can you please explain by an example if possible @TejaNandamuri

Comment: How do you draw the hard circle? Instead of a circle you could draw a radial gradient image with 1.0 alpha white in the middle and 0.0 alpha at the edge and blend that image with your input. This should yield the soft edges you want.